# Android SDK and Path

Tags: command-line, bash, android, sdk

Since I've downloaded the Android development kit as a package (sdk, eclipse bundled together), I extracted it into `/opt/android/sdk`

I ran the command `nano ~/.bashrc` command and opened the file. Now I set the path as below

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android/sdk/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android/sdk/platform-tools
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME ={PATH}:/opt/android/sdk
```

But it doesn't seem to help at all, when I run `ddms` in command prompt I get error message saying `no command ddmds found`.

If we set the path variable in windows correctly the `ddms` command would work correctly. I assume its a problem with the way I set the path.

Can someone please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, Google have made a (pre-release stages) all-in-one IDE and SDK handler called [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what happened as I don't know much technical details behind it. but I removed the following line

```
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME ={PATH}:/opt/android/sdk
```

and restarted the terminal and ran `ddms` it worked.

Answer (score 16):

The correct configuration in your case would look like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Note that the environment variable is called `ANDROID_HOME`, not `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`. Also, the third line in your sample was missing a `$` sign (and contained an additional space). Lastly, there is no need to repeat the same path (DRY) - just use the already defined variable.

**EDIT (2020-03-08):**

While the `ANDROID_SDK` environment variable still continues to work for the most part, it has been **deprecated** by Google, and **replaced** with `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. So you might want to use the new name for a new setup.

More details: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables